# How to save time in TimePicker after the phone is turned off?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, timepicker, vibration

I have an alarm notification with operating normally while the phone is connected, but it reiniciaá the prefrências are reset. How to save?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices for persisting information.  The two most common are

1. [Sqlite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)
2. [Using preferences.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html)

Example to set a preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(<Unique string>, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); 

Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(Strings.STATUS_INTERNET, isInternetConnected);
editor.putString(Strings.USER_NAME, userName);
editor.commit();
```

Example to get a preference:

```
isDefaultAccountEnabled = prefs.getBoolean(Strings.DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, true);
```

Comment: i want use preferences